# Show the strikethrough and underline at the same time in the js tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, jstree

I have a problem to show the strikethrough and underline at the same time in the js tree. My code just can show the strikethrough, cannot show the underline in the js tree.

Below is my js function:

```html
    var colorNodes = function(nodelist) {
        var getStrike = function(status) {
      if (status === "0") {
        return "line-through;";
      }  else {
        return "";
      }
    };
        var getUnderline = function(add_underline) {
        if (add_underline === "1") {
            return "underline;";
        }  else {
        return "";
        }
        };
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      nodelist.forEach(function(n) {
        tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "color:" + getColor(parseInt(n.text.substr(0, 3), 10))+ ";"+"text-decoration:" + getStrike(n.data.status);
        tree.redraw_node(n.id); //Redraw tree
        colorNodes(n.children); //Update leaf nodes
      });
    };

    $('#folder_jstree').bind('load_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      colorNodes(tree.get_json());
    });


    $('#folder_jstree').bind('hover_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
      $("#" + data.node.id).attr("title", data.node.original.category);
    });

  });
```

This is my json data:

```html
[{"id":"658","parent":"#","text":"100 PENTADBIRAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"659","parent":"#","text":"200 PENGURUSAN TANAH & BANGUNAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"660","parent":"#","text":"300 PENGURUSAN ASET <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"661","parent":"#","text":"400 PENGURUSAN KEWANGAN <span id='category'>JKP<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JKP","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"662","parent":"#","text":"500 PENGURUSAN SUMBER MANUSIA <span id='category'>JKP<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JKP","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"663","parent":"658","text":"100-1 PERUNDANGAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"664","parent":"658","text":"100-2 PERHUBUNGAN AWAM <span id='category'>JKP<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JKP","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"665","parent":"663","text":"100-1-1 PENGGUBALAN-PENYEDIAAN-PINDAAN UNDANG-UNDANG-PERATURAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"666","parent":"663","text":"100-1-2 KHIDMAT NASIHAT <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"667","parent":"665","text":"100-1-1-1 UNDANG-UNDANG KECIL KERJA DI JALAN 1996 <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"668","parent":"665","text":"100-1-1-2 UNDANG-UNDANG KECIL PERUNTUKAN MENGENAI LESEN BERSESAMA (MAJLIS PERBANDARAN) <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"670","parent":"666","text":"100-1-2-1 JABATAN PENGUATKUASAAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"671","parent":"666","text":"100-1-2-2 JABATAN BANGUNAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"672","parent":"664","text":"100-2-1 PUBLISITI, PROMOSI DAN PROTOKOL <span id='category'>JKP<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JKP","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"673","parent":"672","text":"100-2-1-1 PUBLISITI DAN KENYATAAN MEDIA <span id='category'>JKP<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JKP","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"674","parent":"665","text":"100-1-1-3 UNDANG-UNDANG KECIL MENGKOMPAUN KESALAHAN-KESALAHAN (MAJLIS PERBANDARAN KLANG) <span id='category'>JTM (BERHUBUNG KOD 100-1\/1\/2)<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM (BERHUBUNG KOD 100-1\/1\/2)","filing_code_refer":null,"data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":null},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"679","parent":"#","text":"516 JOHN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"680","parent":"679","text":"516-1 DAVID <span id='category'>JTM<\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span><span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"0"},"add_underline":{"add_underline":"1"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}}]
```

This is my js tree output:

[image: Output 1]

For my js tree output example 516-1 DAVID, it can make the strike-through, but cannot make the underline at the same time. Hope someone can guide me how to solve it.

If work, like below the output:

[image: Output 2]

This is my working js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/kz89btox/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return both `underline and line-through` to solve your requirement.

```
if (status === "0") {
   return "line-through underline;";
}
```

Alternative approach. You can call this function and pass proper value to this function to work with.

```
var getDecoration = function(status, underline) {
  if (status === "0" && underline === "1") {
    return "line-through underline;";
  } else if(status === "0") {
    return "line-through;";
  } else if(underline === "1") {
    return "underline;";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But I have two condition variable with status and add_underline, how to make it separate to show the underline and the strike-through

Comment: I have two codition are status === "0" and add_underline === "1"

Comment: I don't understand your data-structure. But you can use one function and then handle all the condition inside that.

Comment: Hi @Sifat Haque. I have a quesiton similar the js coding. If you have time can help me to check it. Thanks. stackoverflow.com/questions/62669094/show-color-in-js-nodes

Comment: @Ong Thanks for mentioning. I found that query of yours is already resolved.

Comment: Ok. Thanks your view my question.